# Disk failure - unable to load operating system

Tags: linux

The server belong to our client having issue with disk failure. This lead to operating system failed to load. As per our reference. This server already end of life and it has rhel 6.10.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT2Ph.jpg)

However after further investigation. I found that there is gpxe - etherboot install on this server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6RP2.jpg)

My questions is how to recover this server?

Answer (score 1):

The disk appears to have failed.  Because the bios couldn't find a bootable disk, it tried to boot from the network using gpxe, but it didn't find a network boot server.

It may be possible to use forensic recovery methods to recover data from the disk.  There are multiple companies that can do this.  However, it may be less expensive to recover any needed data from backups.

Comment: from my opinion the etherboot does not exist. you may refer image snapshot indicate no related interface link shows there are no existing etherboot interface exist..

Answer (score 1):

- Get a new server with support (ideally with hardware raid)
- Install a supported OS
- If the disk is readable, migrate your applications and data, if not, restore it from your backups
- Set up monitoring and keep it updated